# Laravel 4 password confirm doesn't seem to work how I expect it to

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, passwords, eloquent

I am basing my code off of a video on Laracasts.com. [Here is the video](https://laracasts.com/lessons/auth-essentials). My idea is that I could use that validation method to create a user. When I try to confirm the passwords, it doesn't seem to match no matter what. My initial thought was that it is hashing the password prior to validation which causes it to return false no matter what.

Here's all of my code thus far.

**Users Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['username' ,'email', 'password'];

public static $rules = [
        'username' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email', 
        'password' => 'required|confirmed'
];

public function isValid()
{
    $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes()) return true;

    $this->errors = $validation->messages();
    return false;
}
```

**UsersController@Store**

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    if (! $this->user->fill($input)->isValid()) 
    { 
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->user->errors);
    }

    //if the user input is  valid then save it and assign associated role
    $this->user->save();
    $this->user->assignRole(Input::get('role'));

    return Redirect::to('/user')->with('flash_message', 'User added to the database!');
}
```

**Create User View - Form**

```
    {{ Form::open(['role' => 'form', 'route' => 'user.store']) }}
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{ Form::label('username', 'First Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('username', null, ['placeholder' => 'First Name', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
            {{ Form::text('email', null, ['placeholder' => 'Last Name', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{ Form::label('role', 'Role') }}
            {{ Form::select('role', $roles, "member", ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
            {{ Form::password('password',  ['placeholder' => 'Password', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password Confirm') }}
            {{ Form::password('password_confirmation',  ['placeholder' => 'Password Confirm', 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            {{ Form::submit('Create User', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your `password_confirmation` field is always empty, no matter what you enter.

This is because you are using `$this->user->fill($input)` within the `store` method. However, in your model you have

```
protected $fillable = ['username' ,'email', 'password'];
```

So, this will never fill the `password_confirmation` field.

If you change the `fillable` to the following, you should have no problems

```
protected $fillable = ['username' ,'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I thought that and when I added password_confirmation to the fillable field, I got an error stating that the column does not exist in the DB. 

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password_confirmation' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `password_confirmation`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test test@gmail.com, password, password, 2014-08-15 13:54:33, 2014-08-15 13:54:33)) Should I add that to the database although that doesn't seem like the right thing to do?

Comment: No, thats not a good idea. You can do the following: In you controller, right before `$this->user->save();` unset that variable so that the ORM doesn't have to look for that on the database. You can unset that with `unset($this->user->password_confirmation);`

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for your help. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to upvote yet but I will if I can!